# embed html into iframe in an vue3 vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I an writing an vue3 web app using vite. I am using an dev framework call vue-vben-admin.
I try to embed an local html into iframe, but the iframe page keep showing the homepage
I put "test.html" in public/static/test.html
so my iframe page would be

```
<iframe id="f1" ref="frame1" :src="'static/test.html'"></iframe>
<iframe id="f2" ref="frame2" :src="'/static/test.html'"></iframe>
```

either ways it just won't work as expected.
The actual iframe url is "https://localhost:3100/static/test.html"

It seems that won't be an 404 problem because when I use Image, the following code work fine:

```
<Image src="/resource/img/logo.png" />
```

Comment: You could try adding any static images and html files directly to the public directory?

Comment: static resource in public like image work fine, html files not. I think it might be intercept by develop framework

Answer (score 0):

For me it just worked when I added the html file to the public folder, but then I had to omit the '/static', so I used
`<iframe id="f1" ref="frame1" :src="'/test.html'"></iframe>`